# ANGULAR: checkbox on form does not become checked when value from API is returned until I submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I've been stuck on what seems like a very simple problem for the last hour and a half now and any help would be infinitely appreciated because it is driving me insane.

I have a checkbox on a form that I want to appear as checked when the its model that's returned from the API is equal to 1, and not checked when the value is 0. I'm using a very simple checkbox for it.

The `checkbox`, however is not checked when I load the form and the API returns a value of 1. When I click on the button that submits the entire form, however, the `checkbox` THEN becomes checked. If I reload the page, the checkbox goes back to being unchecked. Is there something I'm missing here?

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Make Payment Optional</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 center-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"class="center-checkbox" ng-model="formData.paymentMode" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" validate-servererror="paymentMode"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the code that sets the value from the API?

Answer (score 1):

The code is working just fine in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/jyWzVm). I'm setting in the controller the model:

```
  $scope.formData = {
    paymentMode : 1
  }
```

Actually sounds like a problem with the digest cycle, as if you were assigning the model somewhere else, maybe a promise or not inside an angular scope?. If this is true, angular is not refreshing the view because it doesn't know about the change, but it refreshes in the digest cycle that occurs when you submit the form.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's exactly what's going on. I have no idea how to fix this though. If I could just use a true/false for this checkbox all of these problems would go away but a requirement is for this to use ints.

Comment: When the controller loads, I have a formData object that's empty. It then calls the API and fills up the formData inside a promise. Submitting the form uses a different API endpoint, though.

Comment: Can you share the code? Is not pretty but you can manually call the apply() method to do a digest. Two ways of doing that: 1. just call $scope.apply() at the end of your promise. 2. Put all your promise inside the apply $scope.apply(function (){...}).